# Java Swing program with shared database on LAN

Tags: java, transactions

I am making an inventory management program which has a Swing GUI as front end, with multiple users on LAN sharing a database.

I have successfully made my GUI components and a local DB and run the program as per my requirements on a standalone pc(without networking).

Now, I need some insight as to how to scale my application to a network environment. I have already tried the following and it fails:

Having MSACCESS on one of the computers, I make a connection to the db with DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:////COMPUTER-PC/admin/DB.accdb");

All works well, however when 2 users are simultaneously connecting to the database, after certain update queries from both users, the data does not remain consistent. I am stuck here. How to manage the data and maintain consistency.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a 2-tier architecture (client-db).

In most cases you want to have the business logic, consistency check etc. on the backend and thus a 3-tier architecture (client-backend-db).

You can e.g. use Spring Boot to create a simple backend.
[Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) can get you started e.g. with Spring Web (MVC), Spring Data JPA and [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url) (if you don't need to use MS Access) module selected.

The downsides are:

- you need a server to run the Spring Boot JAR. But you can also run it on the machine currently running MS Access.
- you need to think about client-backend communication, e.g. using REST. But there are many samples on the Internet, e.g. using Spring RestTemplate or Spring WebClient.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems little basic to me .

This book by Martin Fowler is little old but It will give you a solid foundation .

Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture Hardcover
by Martin Fowler